# Trying to create a function - but getiing this error. PL/SQL: Statement ignored 10/8 PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, plsql

While I am trying to create the function shown here, I get this error.:

> PL/SQL: Statement ignored 10/8
> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Can we use an associative array with a function?

```
create or replace function pro1 return emp%rowtype
is
    type e_list is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    r_cur e_list;
begin
    for x in 100..110 loop
        select * 
        into r_cur(x) 
        from employees 
        where employee_id = x;

        dbms_output.put_line(r_cur(x).first_name);
    end loop;

    return r_cur;
end;
```

Comment: why are you trying to create this as a _function_ ?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Comment: If it's going to `return emp%rowtype`, why does it return `r_cur e_list`? e_list is not emp%rowtype, is it? I'm a bit puzzled by the name 'r_cur' as well. `r_` means "return"? "record"? Why `_cur`?

Answer (score 1):

The table has the signature:

```sql
function pro1 return emp%rowtype
```

So the function should return a single instance of `emp%rowtype`.

You are returning:

```sql
return r_cur;
```

Which is defined as the variable type:

```sql
r_cur e_list;
```

Which, in turn, the type is defined as:

```sql
type e_list is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
```

An associative array of `emp%rowtype` is not the same as a single instance of `emp%rowtype`.

It is unsurprising that you are getting the error:

> ```
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> 10/8 PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> ```

---

> can we use associative array with function?

Yes, but you need to declare the associative array outside the function and you need to declare the associative array as the return type in the function's signature.